# What condition is needed on $S$ and $T$ such that $C(S,T)$ be compact.

Tags: metric-spaces

If $C(T,S)$ is the set of all continuos function between $T$ and $S$ metric spaces and $S$ compact with the uniform metric. What conditions are needed on $T$ and $S$ such that $C(T,S)$ be compact?

This is related with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1104044/compact-metric-space-implies-that-the-hyperspace-is-compact?noredirect=1#comment2251007_1104044 .

I would like some hint, not the complete answer.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the topology on $C(T,S)$?  The usual choice is the uniform topology, but $C(T,S)$ is typically not compact in this topology.

Comment: In the asumptions $T$ and $S$ are compact.

Comment: Doesn't help.  For example, $C([0,1],[0,1])$ is not compact in the uniform topology; if $f_n(x) = x^n$ then $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence with no convergent subsequence.  So I ask again: What is the topology on $C(T,S)$?

Comment: I will edit the question.

Comment: The edit doesn't help address Nate's question. To talk about $C(T,S)$ being compact, you need to put a topology on it. When $T$ and $S$ are metric spaces (or I guess uniform spaces), the uniform topology is a natural choice, which is why he mentioned it. What topology do you want to use?

Comment: I edit again. The topology is the uniform topology.